# Iterating through string to find missing numbers not working

Tags: php, strpos

The following code *should* print **`,2,6,7,8`** - At least I *want* it to. what the heck am I missing? The intent is to find missing numerals in a long number.

```
$x = 1;
$missing = "";
$newfname = "193555415493359"; 
while($x <= 9) {
    $pos = strpos($newfname,$x);
    if($pos === false) {        
        $missing .= ",$x";                  
    }
    $x++;
} 
echo $missing;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the function documentation](http://www.php.net/strpos), "If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character." In other words, if you pass it 9, it's looking for a tab character (ASCII 9.)

Try this instead:

```
$x = 1;
$missing = "";
$newfname = "193555415493359"; 
while($x <= 9) {
    $pos = strpos($newfname, (string)$x);
    if($pos === false) {        
        $missing .= ",$x";                  
    }
    $x++;
} 
echo $missing;
```

The only change is to [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) `$x` as a string for the search.

Though, this could be done more efficiently:

```
$haystack = "193555415493359";
$needles = "123456789";
$missing = array_diff(str_split($needles), str_split($haystack));
echo implode(",", $missing);
```

Comment: This is a good way, but my first thought was `$pos = strpos($newfname, "$x");` and of course less intuitive `$pos = strpos($newfname, $x+48);`

Comment: I'm a fan of explicit casts. My PHP code is full of (unnecessary?) casts because I like to pretend I'm working in a strongly-typed language.